# Is there ways to implement many to many relation in JMS without selectors?

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

how can i implement this model:
Many users consumes messages from many topics.

In fact messages will be events from those topics that will be show to end user by long polling.

Subscriptions may overlap.

As you understand there can be many subscriptions, so i don't think selectors is the best way to do that. Also i doubt, that creating consumer for each subscription of each user doesn't scale well with growing amount of users.

i'm using ActiveMQ 5

Thanks for you answers.

Comment: I would store the events somewhere and just notify the user that there are new events for him, then he will get them from the store. That way you minimize the message size on the queues.

Comment: This is how it is designed to work. Do you know its any issue, or do imagine it might be an issue?

Comment: Cab you use `Temporary Topics` - 1 for each user? That should not have scaling issues.

Comment: events will be stored in MySQL for statistics and later use(viewing them on the events page). I use mq only for notify online users about events. But even if i will notify user about simple event i'm still need to send to all users, subscribed to that topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use topics and activemq wildcards for your subscriptions
http://activemq.apache.org/wildcards.html

for example: one destination for each message type, every user subscibes to all topics he wants either by using wildcards or by supplying a list of destinations (the activemq ressource adapter accepts a semi-colon seperated list of destinations when creating one)

```
session.createTopic("first;second;any.children.>;only.*.those")
```

a consumer on this topic gets all messages for the topics: 
first
second
any.children (and any of its hirarchy children)
only..those

Comment: thanks a lot for this. Didn't know that i can use several topic names when creating a topic